# For which values of $k$ can $( x +y +z)^2 + k(x^2 +y^2 +z^2)$ be resolved into linear rational factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

My first attempt : Tried to solve by polynomial formulas but can't proceed after few steps.
Second attempt : Tried by vectors  but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

If $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2ryz+2sxz+2txy$ is a homogeneous quadratic
in three variables, then it can only
split into linear factors if the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&r&s\\r&b&t\\s&t&c\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
Here, that determinant is
$$\begin{vmatrix}k+1&1&1\\1&k+1&1\\1&1&k+1\end{vmatrix}.$$